# How to replace properties in application.properties in src/main/resources in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am using Spring boot application and having application.properties property file in src/main/resources. It has some properties which needs to replaced by external property file. I will pass the external file location in command line.

Need solution how to replace the properties inside application with external properties.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException, MQException, IOException {

    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("Application.properties");
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(input);
    properties.load(new FileReader(args[0]));

    SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(new Object[]{ChapsSchemeFeed.class});
    springApplication.setDefaultProperties(properties);
    springApplication.run(args);
}
```

In this code, I am reading properties from command line and loading them with application.properties residing in application. But when I start, its loading properties from Application.properties. But I want to replace it with property from command line properties file.

Comment: Hi Dilip. Better to write your code first and then ask for help from people.

Answer (score 1):

From the Spring Boot manual:

> Spring Boot uses a very particular `PropertySource` order that is designed to allow sensible overriding of values. Properties are considered in the following order:
>
> 1. Devtools global settings properties in the `$HOME/.config/spring-boot` folder when devtools is active.
> 2. [`@TestPropertySource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html) annotations on your tests.
> 3. `properties` attribute on your tests. Available on [`@SpringBootTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.2.RELEASE/api//org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html) and the test annotations for testing a particular slice of your application.
> 4. Command line arguments.
> 5. Properties from `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON` (inline JSON embedded in an environment variable or system property).
> 6. `ServletConfig` init parameters.
> 7. `ServletContext` init parameters.
> 8. JNDI attributes from `java:comp/env`.
> 9. Java System properties (`System.getProperties()`).
> 10. OS environment variables.
> 11. A `RandomValuePropertySource` that has properties only in `random.*`.
> 12. Profile-specific application properties outside of your packaged jar (`application-{profile}.properties` and YAML variants).
> 13. Profile-specific application properties packaged inside your jar (`application-{profile}.properties` and YAML variants).
> 14. Application properties outside of your packaged jar (`application.properties` and YAML variants).
> 15. Application properties packaged inside your jar (`application.properties` and YAML variants).

References:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html